# What kind of activation is used by ScikitLearn's MLPClasssifier in output layer?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

I am currently working on a classification task with given class labels 0 and 1. For this I am using ScikitLearn's `MLPClassifier` providing an output of either 0 or 1 for each training example. However, I can not find any documentation, what the output layer of the MLPClassifier is exactly doing (which activation function? encoding?).

Since there is an output of only one class I assume something like One-hot_encoding is used. Is this assumption correct? Is there any documentation tackling this question for the `MLPClassifier`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`out_activation_` attribute would give you the type of activation used in the output layer of your MLPClassifier.

**[From Documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.predict_proba)**

> **out_activation_ :** string
>   Name of the output activation function.

The `activation` param just sets the hidden layer's activation function.

> **activation :** {‘identity’, ‘logistic’, ‘tanh’, ‘relu’}, default ‘relu’
>   Activation function for the hidden layer.

The output layer is decided internally in [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L267) piece of code.

```
# Output for regression
if not is_classifier(self):
    self.out_activation_ = 'identity'
# Output for multi class
elif self._label_binarizer.y_type_ == 'multiclass':
    self.out_activation_ = 'softmax'
# Output for binary class and multi-label
else:
    self.out_activation_ = 'logistic'
```

Hence, for binary classification it would be `logistic` and for multi-class it would be `softmax`.

To know more details about these activations, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/neural_network/_base.py#L29).

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the information in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). The MLP is a simple neural network. It can use several activation functions, the default is `relu`.

It doesn't use one-hot encoding, rather you need to feed in a `y` (target) vector with class labels.

Comment: Hello Josh, thank you for your answer. I know that I can choose relu, identity, tanh and logistic, but my question is about the output layer. Usually, for multilayer classification you would get either probabilities for each class or something like [100], [001],...  . MLPClassifier is giving me ONE output. So how is it processed  in the output layer? That is actually my question.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the last activation function is the logistic function, and the output is set to 1 if the probability is >0.5 and to 0 otherwise.

However, you can output the probability if you want.