# Are hidden layers of sklearn's MLPClassifier() the same as Dense layer of keras/tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, mlp

Theoretically and practically, are the hidden layers of MLPclassifier (refer to hidden_layer_sizes)

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(4, 3, 2, 1),
                       max_iter = 100, activation = 'relu',
                       solver = 'adam', verbose = type_spec_from_value,
                       random_state = 100, learning_rate = 'invscaling',
                       early_stopping=False
                       )
```

the same as the Dense layers of tensorflow/keras

```
mlp = Sequential()
mlp.add(Dense(4))
mlp.add(Dense(3))
mlp.add(Dense(2))
mlp.add(Dense(3))
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. In both cases, the parameters specify the number of neurons.

Comment: Thank you! I also want to ask whether the "activation" on sklearn's MLPClassifier() is applied for every hidden layer? Or just the output? Because in Keras/TensorFlow, I notice we can define the activation for every layer, but I'm not sure how the sklearn's works.

Comment: In scikit-learn, it is only used for the hidden layers, and you cannot directly specify the activation of the output layer. See here for a discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337843/what-kind-of-activation-is-used-by-scikitlearns-mlpclasssifier-in-output-layer